# Is there a built-in that converts character to Ascii / Unicode

Tags: freemarker

something that could be like `${'c'?unicode}` whould print `63` I went over the list of built-ins and didn't find anything like it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, as of 2.3.27. It has come up for a few times, also the opposite of it (number to character), so maybe in 2.3.28. But, what's the use case?

Comment: in this case, i had a wierd return from a build-in function that i had to deal with. it was showing as Unicode Replacement Character `U+FFFD`. as I understood it might be a case of the system getting an unrecognized character code and displaying it as Replacement Character. So I thought by getting the code of the character will provide me more info to what it was. Eventually it was NaN, so the use of freemarker's ?is_nan worked for me.

Comment: You don't need anything special for that, it's just a string comparison: `s == '\xFFFD'`. (Or if it's only about one  character, then compare with `s[someIndex]`.)